# How to add sessions, tables, etc in MATLAB comments

Tags: matlab

The official help of MATLAB functions can have sessions, texts in different styles and tables for for example 'Name-Value Pair Arguments'. See [the help of arrayfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). Can we do the same thing for user-defined functions?

Comment: MATLAB's documentation [is HTML/XML based](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-documentation.html). It's separate from the comments.